# preg_match_all extract from a text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, string-parsing

I'm trying to use preg_match_all to extract an array from a text array format:

explanation: i've this kind of texte

```
mynicetext
text with other elements
|my first Column            |my second column   |
|my data in first column    |data 2             |    
|my data in first column    |data 3             |       
....   
other text
text with other elements
|my first Column            |my second column   | My last column |
|my data in first column    |data 2             |data 2          |     
|my data in first column    |data 3             |data 2          |
....
```

I want to extract a full array like this:

```
|my first Column            |my second column   |
|my data in first column    |data 2             |    
|my data in first column    |data 3             |
```

I've tried to use this to `~(\s*\n)\|(.*)\|(\s*\n)~` to extract but i cut lines caused by the carriage return.

```
|my first Column            |my second column   |
```

then

```
|my data in first column    |data 2             |
```

...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with preg_match_all:

```
$pattern = '~(?:^\|.*\n)+~m';
```